# Login form using ASP.NET MVC with stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stored-procedures

I have encountering error regarding my login form.

Here's the controller for login, in the Immediate Window the value of parameters that will be passed in stored procedure

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("EDMSConnectionString")))
{
    connection.Open();

    var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.ValidateLogin", connection);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", model.Username);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", model.Password);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", model.Role);

    var result = (bool)command.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
    }
}
```

[image]

In the stored procedure, the return value is 1. I'm confused why I'm getting result false.

[image]

This is the stored procedure script:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ValidateLogin]
    @Username VARCHAR(50),
    @Password VARCHAR(50),
    @Role VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @Result bit;

    SELECT 
        @Result = CASE 
                      WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 
                          THEN 1 
                          ELSE 0 
                  END
    FROM 
        tblLogin
    WHERE 
        Username = @Username 
        AND Password = @Password 
        AND Role = @Role;

    RETURN @Result
END
```

Comment: Hello everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Below code useful to me.

[image]

```
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_configuration.GetConnectionString("SqlDataContextConnection")))
            {
               connection.Open();

               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ValidateLogin", connection);  
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;   
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar));
               cmd.Parameters["@Username"].Value = '2';
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar));
               cmd.Parameters["@Password"].Value = '1';
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Role", SqlDbType.VarChar));
               cmd.Parameters["@Role"].Value = '1';
               cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@return", SqlDbType.Int));
               cmd.Parameters["@return"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

               return Ok(cmd.Parameters["@return"].Value.ToString());
            }
```